# How to write javascript in MVC4 C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working in mvc 4, I have same action name with multiple view, so i cant write javascript in all pages, Simple write the javascript in action result in c# only.

Actually i am trying like below, but its troughs an error,

```
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "swal({ title: 'Dear User', text: " + TempData["MACNotice"] + ", type: 'warning',}, function () { var zip_file_path = window.location.href + '/MACSetting.zip'; var zip_file_name = 'MAC Setting'; var a = document.createElement('a'); document.body.appendChild(a); a.style = 'display: none'; a.href = zip_file_path; a.download = zip_file_name; a.click(); document.body.removeChild(a);}););", true);
```

Error be like :-

> Argument 1: cannot convert from
>      'ParentLogins.Controllers.SigninController' to
>      'System.Web.UI.Control'
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from
>      'ParentLogins.Controllers.SigninController' to 'System.Web.UI.Page'

Please help me, because the lot of views are there if any possible in c# let me know, or any other options are there for write javascript, not write in all views.

Comment: The errors that you have posted are not related to the line of code in your post.

Comment: Why dont put your javascript code in the Layout.cshtml?

Comment: Mr Thangadurai,  Please click the below link, what i get the error. https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-02w1MRFiyGw/XYsES5M_B_I/AAAAAAAAB8c/3zTXE3Ez4WA-5uVwu7BAbEm0yoGm25zRwCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2019-09-24.png

Comment: Mr, Gurol Mehmet, There have no master page in my project for login page.

Comment: You are trying to use Asp.net webforms code in Asp.net Mvc. We cannot teach you how to get started with asp.net mvc. Read some docs first. its a different project type to say the least.

Comment: `any other options are there for write javascript?`. You write it in a javascipt file(.js extension) and include it with a script tag.

Comment: Yes i know Mr. Mat J, i am using asp.net code in mvc if u know any other way to reach for the problems, please let me know.

Comment: Can you share your folder structure in the question please?

Comment: Mr. Gürol Mehmet Cetin, ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "KEY", "$(document).ready(function (){ });", true); through an error below link
 https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-zn4dk3G_trY/XYsJwPITj2I/AAAAAAAAB8w/G663z5rL7IwfpKTmav9TGeDsOLxFMK5_gCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2019-09-24.png

Comment: Mr. Gürol Mehmet Cetin, MVC Structure, only anction result with multiple views, 
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-oVGxuLU8PX0/XYsK7tb6FNI/AAAAAAAAB88/wNB8s6Eqw78NnRs2UuzYeFkjZsVXvt_jwCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2019-09-24.png

Comment: IDK maybe this class dont work in mvc. Cause this code work on my own project. You should find the other way to add your script on your page :)

Comment: Mr,  Gürol Mehmet Cetin, please share the code working in your project and please screen shot the page, I think those are helpfull to me, please share those code

Comment: This code work on Web Forms project. If this code doesn't work when you put your script in the function below. I'm sorry you have to find other way for add script on your page. I'll try this in MVC project. If it's work i'll coomment here.

Comment: Mr. Gürol Mehmet Cetin, I got the solution.

 HttpContext.Response.Write("<script  type='text/javascript'> alert('hello');</script>");

Comment: That's unnecessary and a bad idea. Just write a script tag directly into your cshtml view file, like a regular web page. And I suggest that you find the official Microsoft MVC tutorial online and work through it...then you'll start to understand the basics including this kind of difference

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to add script in the Mvc project .cs file.

> Indeed, ScriptManager and just about all the script-related APIs on
>   the Page class are not supported in MVC View Pages.
>
> If you want script in a View Page, you can just place the script code
>   there directly - no need to call any helper methods.

[Origin](https://forums.asp.net/t/1496613.aspx?How%20to%20use%20ScriptManager%20RegisterClientScriptBlock%20in%20asp%20net%20mvc%20)

And you can call your javascript function in the .cshtml file.

eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function (){ 
    alert("WORK");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
HttpContext.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'> alert('hello');</script>");
```

Comment: That's unnecessary and a bad idea. Just write a script tag directly into your cshtml view file, like a regular web page. See [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58092781/5947043)